# Mongoose: findOneAndUpdate returns strange structure

Tags: mongoose

```
  a = await db.a.findOneAndUpdate({id}, {...doc}, {
    upsert: true,
    new: true
  });
  b = await db.b.findOneAndUpdate({id}, {...doc}, {
    upsert: true,
    new: true
  });
```

a returns normal result

```
{...}
```

b returns strange result

```
{
    "$__":
    {
        "strictMode": true,
        ...
    },
    "isNew": false,
    "_doc":
    {
        ...
    },
    "$init": true
}
```

Instead of returning the document in a object, Mongoose returns the doc in in a strange structure within `_doc` object.

P.S., setting `rawResult` false doesn't help.

These are the model a and model b:

```
db.a = mongoose.model('a', (Schema, ObjectId) => new Schema({
    objectid: ObjectId,
    title: String
}));
```

```
db.b = mongoose.model('b', (Schema, ObjectId) => new Schema({
    objectid: ObjectId,
    text: String
}));
```

It turns out to be a Mongoose bug...after killing the Node process and restart it, it behaves normally now.

Comment: Please share your models. It appears to me that you aren't using mongoose appropriately, and that could be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a Mongoose bug...after killing the Node process and restart it, it behaves normally now.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, you are not supplying `findOneAndUpdate()` a callback. According the the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate), `findOneAndUpdate()` "...returns the found document (if any) to the callback. The query executes if `callback` is passed else a Query object is returned."

Below are their provided examples of how to call this function, and notice the examples not calling the `callback` (which is similar to how you're calling it) return the `Query`.

```
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, options)  // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, callback) // executes
A.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update)           // returns Query
A.findOneAndUpdate()                             // returns Query
```

Comment: Notice there is `await` before the query, meaning the result is the resolved promise of the query. In this case, query is the desired result. Also your answer doesn't explain why `db.a` returns correct format while `db.b` returns false format.